# Return both a base plot and ggplot from function

Tags: r, ggplot2, plot

I'm trying to make a function that produces a few plots for visual evaluation.  I generally use ggplot for most purposes, but the base plot for models is helpful as well. When I try to assign the base plot, it produces the plot, but doesn't assign it to the variable, so when I try to return the plots (using `list()`) the base plot doesn't show up and returns the ggplot plus a [NULL]

Toy example

```
library(tidyverse)
my.fun = function(){
      mod.lm = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
      p1 = mtcars %>%
            ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = disp))+
            geom_point()
      par(mfrow = c(2,2))
      p2 <- plot(mod.lm)
      list(p1, p2)
}
my.fun()
```

Comment: base plots cannot be assigned to objects. It's one of the fundamental differences between base graphics and `grid` graphics (`ggplot2` is built on `grid` graphics). You can have a function draw a base plot, but it cannot be assigned or returned.

Comment: @GregorThomas drawing the base plot would work fine, as long as the plot is visible outside the function, so when I call my.fun() both are drawn in the plots window?  I'm using this for eda and don't need to save the plots but want to compare several of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've never used base plot, but in a few attemps and coming across recordPlot(), as @user2554330 (beat me for 2 minutes) says, you can save both plots. Changing the order of plot() and ggplot() worked for me so first plot() is called and not overwritte ggplot() output. Also you can store the list in a variable and call the objects then.

```
library(tidyverse)
library(mtcars)
library(ggplot2)
my.fun = function(){
  mod.lm = lm(mpg ~ disp, data = mtcars)
  par(mfrow = c(2,2))
  plot(mod.lm)
  p1 <-  recordPlot() 
  p2 <-  mtcars %>%
    ggplot(aes(x = disp, y = disp))+
    geom_point()
  list(p1, p2)
}
my.fun()
a <- my.fun()
```

Answer (score 2):

Base plotting functions write directly to a plotting device, unlike ggplot2 functions, which produce an object that does the writing when you print it.  It's possible to save a base plot (using the `recordPlot()` function), but it is already adapted to whatever output device it was using, and won't look as good if displayed (using `replayPlot()`) on a different device.

Comment: So does that mean to use `list(p1, replayPlot(plot(mod.lm)))` in the function?

Comment: No, see @RobertoT's answer, but do pay attention to the warnings in the help page for `recordPlot`.